# lua creating a table to add to a table giving me 'index is nil' error

Tags: lua

Below is the entire code. I'm trying to add a screen to a screen table with the name as the key but on that line (noted below) I get the error 'index is nil' and I'm not sure why. I'm simply adding an element to the screens table with the given 'name' key.

```
element = {}

function element:element(name, tags)
   local obj = {}

   obj.name = name
   obj.tags = tags

   for k,v in pairs(element) do
      obj[k] = v
   end

   return obj
end

function element:getName()
   return self.name
end

function element:onClick(callback)
   self.clickCallback = callback
   return self
end

function element:click()
   self.clickCallback()
end

--=======================================

screen = {}

function screen:screen(name)
   local obj = {}

   obj.name = name
   obj.elements = {}

   for k,v in pairs(screen) do
      obj[k] = v
   end
   print("creating screen")
   return obj
end

function screen:addElement(e)
   self.elements[e:getName()] = e
end

function screen:update()
   -- for testing
   self.elements["profile1"]:click()
end

--=======================================

ui = {}
ui.screens = {}

function ui:screen(name)
   if ui.screens[name] == nil then
      ui.screens[name] = screen:screen(name)    --<---- ERROR: index is nil
   end

   return ui.screens[name]
end

function ui:element(name, tags)
   return element:element(name, tags)
end

--local e = ui.element("profile1", "profile_button btnProfile1")
ui.screen("profiles"):addElement(
   ui.element("profile1", "profile_button btnProfile1")
      :onClick(function() print("Profile1 button clicked")
      end)
)

ui.screen("profiles"):update()
```

Comment: `ui:screen("profiles"):update()`

Comment: So is this a matter of because I defined the functions with the : way instead of the other way (ui.screen = function()end) I need to do this because ui doesn't use any sort of 'self' inside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions that you have defined using the "[method syntax](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10)" (with `:`'s) are simply syntactic sugar for a function that takes a self object as a hidden first parameter.

As the [Lua reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10) describes it:

> The form
>
> functioncall ::= prefixexp ‘:’ Name args can be used to call
>   "methods". A call v:name(args) is syntactic sugar for v.name(v,args),
>   except that v is evaluated only once.

So every time you call these methods you will have to pass a self argument as well. This can be done easily like so: `object:method(argument1, argument2)`.

(Note that since this is only syntactic sugar, you could also pass self directly like this: `object.method(object, argument1, argument2)`)

You get the error you do since you use the normal `.` syntax and do not provide a self argument. Instead the first argument you pass: "profiles" is assigned to self which is why the `name` variable is `nil`.